# Ruby undefined method `encode' for String

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get [this](http://codepad.org/nh6cAqHT) code to work (ruby 1.8.7):

```
line = "abc" 
"#{line}☃".encode('utf-8')[0..-2].scan(/\p{Katakana}/)
```

but it returns `undefined method 'encode' for "abc\342\230\203":String (NoMethodError)`.

You can run the program here: http://codepad.org/nh6cAqHT

Comment: What is the version of ruby that you are using?

Comment: please specify what ruby version you are having that issue on the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably using an older version of ruby. It is [available in 1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode)
but [not in 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html), so check which version you're using.

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > line = "abc"
 => "abc" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > "#{line}☃".encode('utf-8')[0..-2].scan(/\p{Katakana}/)
 => []
```

Works fine.

Comment: I haven't even thought to check that. I thought codepad was using the latest. `rvm use 1.9.3` did it

Comment: The second command line won't work on my irb, why could that be? `SyntaxError: (irb):3: invalid character property name {Katakana}: /\p{Katakana}/` (running ruby 2.1.5 on Windows)